# Wiki to replace Microsoft Word

Tags: web-apps, cms, document-management, wiki, wysiwyg

## Background

An organization has a vast number of MS Word documents. Pertinent MS Word features include:

- Simplicity: just edit and go ([WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)).
- Track changes.
- Visual table editor.

There are a number of issues with MS Word:

- Inability to easily change the look and feel of all documents simultaneously.
- Revisions are dated and recorded manually (usually a table near the start of the document).
- No revision control (cannot easily compare differences, nor roll back).
- Cannot easily embed document fragments.
- Cannot readily search all documents without a content management system.
- Directory structure is often used as a poor CMS substitute.

Migrating the documentation from MS Word to a web-based system should be fast, simple, and as automated as possible.

## Problem

Although MediaWiki addresses many of these issues, its [VisualEditor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor) is missing critical functionality that would make the transition from MS Word frustrating, time-consuming, and painful, such as:

- its [table editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/VisualEditor/Design/Table_editor) does not yet exist;
- document editing has a cluttered user interface; and
- the simplicity of track changes is not available.

## Question

What wiki:

- uses a visual editor
- includes an advanced in-browser table editor
- has a simple user interface
- provides an easy way to track changes
- allows for comments, notes, and suggestions
- can include snippets from other wiki pages (single source!)
- generates Markdown that [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can use
- is cross-browser compatible (IE9+, Chrome, FF30+)
- is FOSS or available for self-hosting
- optionally, provides a facility to transfer document version history (author and date)

## Related

Related software, ideas, and blogs include:

- http://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2011/07/27/your-wysiwyg-editor-sucks/
- http://wymeditor.github.io/wymeditor/dist/examples/01-basic.html
- http://dillinger.io/
- http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/WYSIWYG
- http://scottnesbitt.net/ubuntublog/turning-a-wiki-into-a-writing-environment/

Comment: Not using it myself, but a previous customer had it running and I "used it once": [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29) should cover that AFAIR. You even can import existing office documents. I cannot compare your full feature list (as I don't use this product), and don't know about your budget (you might wish to [edit] your post and include a hint on that), but it might at least be a pointer.

Comment: What do you mean by "an easy way to track changes"? MediaWiki definitely has that. VisualEditor now supports tables, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XWiki offers a generic platform for developing projects and collaborative applications using the wiki paradigm. It meets most of, if not all, the requirements can extend functionality via plugins.

https://www.xwiki.org

Answer (score 2):

As the comment on the original post suggested, Atlassian Confluence might be a good choice. I use it every day to document product requirements. I believe it satisfies all of the requirements in your "Question" section, although I'm not sure about "generates Markdown that pandoc can use".

I work for a small company and we run a self-hosted version of Confluence on a VM. There is a cost associated to it, depending on how many users you need, but I believe you get what you pay for.