# Comprehensive Technical Documentation Tool

Tags: pdf, wiki, markdown, documentation-generator

## Background

Looking to unify technical documentation, bridging computer- and user-generated content, using open source tools. The goal is to write (or generate) content in an output agnostic file format, which is then transformed into a final document. The figure below helps illustrate how the overall pieces connect.

[image: Documentation architecture]

The solution should be operating system independent.

## Output Features

The final document must include:

- Tables
- Figures
- Code Snippets
- Auto-numbered captions (for tables, figures, and code snippets)
- Cross-references (hyperlinked to tables, figures, and bibliographic citations)
- Headings (up to seven levels; 1., 1.1., ..., 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.)
- Appendices (up to seven levels; A., A.1, ..., A.1.1.1.1.1.1.)
- Auto-numbered headings and appendices
- Table of Contents (hyperlinked)
- List of Tables (hyperlinked)
- List of Figures (hyperlinked)
- Bibliography (books, articles, journals, whitepapers, websites [hyperlinked])

  - Variety of formats (APA, Chicago, IEEE, etc.)

Most importantly, stylization (through templates or coding) should be possible so that all the documentation can be re-generated with a new look and feel. [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page), for example, excels at this.

Markdown and Pandoc offers much of this functionality, though I'm not sure if it handles cross-references, auto-captions, bibliographies, and code snippets.

## Input Features

- Cross-document [variables](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) (e.g., a server name is documented once, but referenced by application architecture and software requirements specifications).
- Browser-based WYSIWYG editor (possibly Confluence)

  - Table editor
  - [Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion) (embedded excerpts to help single-source content)
  - Collaborative (ideally, real-time)
  - Revisions
  - Markdown (ability to view source, but predominately used like a modern word processor)
- Computer-generated content is transformed into Markdown format:

  - Source code documentation (package descriptions, no hyperlinked content necessary); Javadocs, Doxygen, etc.
  - SNMP (names and IP addresses of network devices)
  - Diagrams (entity-relationships, UML, GraphViz, etc.)

    - Ideally, JPG, PNG, and SVG images could be imported
  - List of database surrogate keys and descriptions (dumped from database)

## Questions

Is it even possible to generate a high-quality technical document that includes such a wide variety of artifacts using only Markdown as the source content?

Here are the pieces that I'd appreciate recommendations or suggestions on:

- Including source code (e.g., Javadoc/Doxygen -> Markdown)
- Possibility to reformat various *nix command outputs to Markdown (`nmap`, `traceroute`, `ls`, `tree`, `df`, SNMP output, etc.); the translation could be massaged using `awk` and `sed`, for example.
- WYSIWYG editor (FOSS [alternatives](http://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard.php) to Confluence)
- FOSS that can handle churning the output features from Markdown source into the desired output formats (PDF definitely and MS Word optionally).

  - If Pandoc/ConTeXt cannot accomplish this feat, what can?
- Software and/or data formats (e.g., Markdown, YAML) for integrating bibliographies and cross-references such that the document generator (e.g., ConTeXt) can use them (e.g., [RStudio](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html))?

If there is a single software package that brings together all these features, I'd be keen to know that, too.

## Related

Related questions include:

- [Wiki to replace Microsoft Word](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/wiki-to-replace-microsoft-word)

### Software

- http://rapporter.github.io/pander/
- http://pandoc.org/
- https://www.r-project.org/

### Specifications

- https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax
- http://blog.martinfenner.org/2013/06/19/citations-in-scholarly-markdown/
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-jsp-135444.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reasonably certain that will a little work you could put something very like what you are describing using [Sphinx Docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/). The one area that you might have problems with is Real Time Collaborative Editing.

- Base format is Restructured Text, (rather than markdown), but inputs can be in markdown.
- Multiple output formats
- Multiple input sources including source code, wiki, on-line, etc.
- Can invoke and post process multiple tools during build process
- Cross Platform
- Open Source
- Produces really good looking documentation
- All of your requested output features available
- Templates - Yes
- Produce multiple output format documents - Yes
- Syntax highlighting of code fragments in multiple languages thanks to Pygments.
- Extensive cross-references: semantic markup and automatic links for functions, classes, citations, glossary terms and similar pieces of information.
- Good internationalisation support using gettext.
- Extensible and actively developed.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like there's an XML builder, which could be used with ConTeXt. as well as what appears to be a [ConTeXt builder](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib) extension.

Comment: In an [example](https://www.yumpu.com/xx/document/view/11722645/masterthesis-markusmayr-0542042) with an appendix, the heading numbers don't use letters. This could have been an oversight/misconfiguration of the engine used to render the PDF, though.

Comment: I have just run some tests based on http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#enumerated-lists and those work fine for auto-enumerated - even the Roman numerals.